# How can I line up this button with the textboxes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I would like the left side of the button flush with the textboxes. I'm using bootstrap 3 if that makes a difference. Here is my html code for the form. I can add my CSS if that's necessary as well. Thank you.

```css
h1 {
     font-size:83px;
    }

    .btn-primary {
     background: #ffffff;
     border-color: #ffffff;
     color: #f05324;
    }

    .btn-default, .btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus, .btn-default:active, .btn-default.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
        background: #ffffff;
     border-color: #ffffff;
     color: #f05324;
    }

    .panel-default {
        border: none;
    }

    input[type="text"] { 
     color:white !important;
    } 

    input[type="email"] { 
     color:white !important;
    } 

    .model-content {
     color:black !important;
    }

    .text-left {
      text-align: left;
    }

    .text-right {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .text-center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    body {
     background: #f05324 !important; 
     margin-bottom: 80px;
     color: #ffffff;
    }

    .page-header, .panel-body, .panel, .panel-default, .col-lg-9, .row {
     background: #f05324 !important; 
    }

    .form-control{
        background-color: #f05324;
        color: #000000;
    }

    hr {
     border-color: #ffffff;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     color: #ffffff;
    }

    .link {
     color: #ffffff;
    }

    .page-header {
     margin-top: 0;
    }

    .panel-body {
     padding-top: 0;
    }

    .img-featured {
     margin-top   : 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     margin-right : 15px;
    }

    .img-project{
     margin-top   : 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .show-onclick {
     display: none;
    }

    .show-onclick1 {
     display: none;
    }

    .block {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: // half the width of your img
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">NAME:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">EMAIL:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phoneNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PHONE:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="major" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MAJOR:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="major" name="major">
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemForSale" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ITEM FOR SALE:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemForSale1" name="itemForSale1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity" class="col-sm-2 control-label">QUANTITY:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity1" name="quantity1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PRICE:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1" name="price1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemOneImg1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IMAGE 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemOneImg1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="itemOneImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IMAGE 2:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemOneImg2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="additional-files" type="button" value="Additional Projects" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Comment: you need to include the code that created the current layout

Comment: probably need to add the css, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the left edge of the button to match up with the left edge of the text boxes then you just need to add an offset using the Bootstrap grid as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemOneImg2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IMAGE 2:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" class="form-control" name="itemOneImg2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Adjust col-sm-X for the buttons to adjust their positioning
             Could also add btn-block class to make the button span the column -->
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
            <input id="additional-files" type="button" value="Additional Projects" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

More details (and another example) can be found on the Bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

EDIT: Based on additional information in comments.

Comment: That worked, however, now it pushed the submit button down http://i.imgur.com/Asnr6hl.png

Comment: You should be able to bring your submit button inside your form and apply a similar approach to it. If you want it on the same line as the 'Additional Files' button, wrap it in a div like the above input, but without the offset, and place it inside the same form-group, but adjust the col span. I can update my solution if you want? (assuming you want it on them on the same line).

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful! On the same line is what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: Increase the col span for the submit button and decrease it for the projects button to move the submit button to the left. Add the 'btn-block' class to make the button fill the width of the column, might need an offset between the buttons (if both use 'btn-block' class). Hope that helped - have a look through the Bootstrap site if you get stuck again, they have good docs and examples.